# Get attribute value out of CActiveDataProvider

Tags: php, yii

I want to store the id of the item in a CActiveDataProvider object inside a html data attribute.

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id'=>'feeds-in-group-grid',
        'dataProvider'=>$data,
        'filter'=>$filter,
        'emptyText'=>"Er zijn geen resultaten gevonden.",
        'columns'=>array(
            array(
                'name'=>'name',
                'htmlOptions'=>array(
                    'data-feed-id'=>1 HERE I NEED THE CURRENT FEED ID
                    )
                ),
            array(
                'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
                'template'=>'{update}',
            ),
        ),
        // 'buttons'=>array(
        //      'url'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('..&id=' . $data->id)
        //  ),
        'loadingCssClass'=>'feeds-group',
        'itemsCssClass'=>'feeds-item',
        'summaryText'=>'Deze groep bevat {count} feed(s)',
        'enablePagination'=>false,
    )
);
```

Does anyone know how to do this in Yii?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a little tinkering of the CDataColumn class, here's a wiki guide:

[CGridView: Use special variable $data in the htmlOptions of a column (i.e. evaluate htmlOptions attribute)](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/314/cgridview-use-special-variable-data-in-the-htmloptions-of-a-column-i-e-evaluate-htmloptions-attribute/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe...

```
'htmlOptions'=>array(
                'data-feed-id'=>'$data->id'
                )
```